# Include APK in AOSP build by symlink

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I'm currently trying to include an APK into my AOSP 10 build. For this I created a new module folder under `packages/apps` and put my APK as well as an Android.mk file into it. Then I added the module to the PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable. This works great when the module under `packages/apps` is a real folder. However, when I replace is through a symlink the app does not appear in the new build. My Android.mk file looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := App1
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := App1.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Do you have any ideas why my app does not show up when the module is a symlink? The `my-dir` macro dissolves to the real path (not the symlink path) if that is any help in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that when creating your symlink, you specified a relative path, rather than an absolute path. So when the build script executes, it is looking in the wrong folder.

See this answer about symlinks to understand what I mean: https://superuser.com/questions/511900/why-doesnt-my-symbolic-link-work